# dateutil parser without defaults

Tags: python, datetime

It is driving me crazy. I really dislike the library, but sadly I've not been able to find anything better.

What's particularly bothering me is that it is giving defaults. It gives the option to change the defaults, but **only** to a `datetime` object.

I'd like to get year and month with certainty, but at this stage there is no way to know for sure whether the month is "real" or whether it has taken the default value.

Simple example:

```
>>> dateutil.parser.parse('')
datetime.datetime(2015, 06, 08, 0, 0, 0) # note that it takes defaults for Y/M/D
```

Of course, the empty string is just a simple example and could be tested differently.

The only way I can think of is to parse everything twice with different defaults, and then only objects that remain equal must be good.

Did anyone find a way to deal with this issue?

Comment: What do you mean by "it is giving defaults"?

Comment: Related: [Parsing a date in python without using a default](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434854/parsing-a-date-in-python-without-using-a-default)

Comment: @LukasGraf Might even be a duplicate, wow... I really thought I might have been the only one to be pulling my hair out over this.